# Proxy Authentication Error

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, proxy-authentication

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com");
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("myname", "mypass");
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("192.168.1.1:8080", false);
myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = myproxy;
myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
MessageBox.Show("Ok");
```

I'm using this code to connect with a website (C#.net desktop application).  But I'm having this error message:

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you need to pass nc into the WebProxy constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently not using the credentials in the proxy. Here is an [example adapted from MSDN of how to use your `NetworkCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx):

```
class Downloader
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(args[0], args[1]);
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(args[2], false);
        proxy.Credentials = nc;

        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(args[3]);
        request.Proxy = proxy;
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                @"{0} - {1} bytes",
                response.ContentType,
                response.ContentLength);
        }
    }
}
```

When I compiled and ran this complete example:

```
C:\cs>csc proxy.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\cs>proxy user pass http://proxy:80 http://www.google.com
text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 - 31398 bytes

C:\cs>
```

<sub>Of course I used my actual user/pass and proxy for my work account.</sub>

Comment: Why do you use `CredentialCache`+`NetworkCredential` instead of just `NetworkCredential`?

Comment: Because I adapted it from the wrong example initially. Corrected, thank you.

Comment: @six: btw, that was not a pestering, but a curiosity :)

Comment: how im having this error message Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid. I have credentials for proxy and as well as username and password for the website i need to be logged in

Comment: @Kevin: you likely need to prepend `http://` to the proxy URI. I've done so in my example.

Comment: @six : having the previous error message: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: @Kevin: if you haven't already done so, you need to remove `myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;`.

Comment: as i have a password and a username for the proxy do i have to add proxy credentials w    ebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("","","");?

Comment: i executed the code without myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy; but still having the same error

Comment: @Kevin: I've updated my answer to include a complete sample that I've run on my machine right now at work, which sits behind a proxy.

Comment: Are there a password and a username for your proxy. i have a password and username for the proxy. Still cant loggin